# Aggregate returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Using mongoose's `Model.aggregate()` returns an empty array.

I've essentially copied the format as seen [here](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2013/08/25/mongoose-aggregate-with-group-by-nested-field/).

```
var match = {};
var project = {};
    project["_id"] = 0;
    project["products.totalprice"] = 1;
    project["line"] = "$products.closedate";

ThisCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: match},
    {$project: project},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$line"
    }}

], function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs); //!! Returning []
});
```

My schema is essentially a `name` and `_id` field with a nested array of products with `totalprice`, `closedate` and some other fields.

There are most certainly a plethora of entries (some 130,000 records). Can anyone spot an issue with this?

Comment: Does the query without the `$group` statement return any results ?

Comment: @Jaco Nope, tried that still empty. Checking over my keys again, but the " missing was a typo on the copy-paste.

Comment: @Jaco Almost... Using $products.totalprice in the `project` object, I'm now getting `undefined` for docs.

Comment: @Jaco Hold the phone... might be something wrong with my data. Give me a moment.

Comment: Please show your document with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this dummy data to represent a skeleton of your schema:

```
db.data.save({name:"a",products:{totalprice:1,closedate:1}})
db.data.save({name:"b",products:{totalprice:2,closedate:2}})
```

This query does return two records and is identical to yours when inserting the JSON string for the JavaScript variable `project`

```
ThisCollection.aggregate([{$match:{}},{$project:{"_id":0,"products.totalprice":1,line:"$products.closedate"}},{$group:{_id:"$line"}}])
```

Comment: My collection was empty.

Comment: Yes,  that doesn't help:-)